# Can I print all the cards (detailed) of a Trello board?

Tags: trello, trello-cards, list, trello-boards

Can I print(/export in .csv or other format) all the cards of a board with the detailed information of each board?

I have several cards with detailed information, checklist, due date... etc but it seem impossible to have this information (particularly the checklist) without opening all the cards.

Is there a way to access all this information (for printing them for a meeting)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this by default, but if you're using Chrome, there is an Extension for this: [Board Printer for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/board-printer-for-trello/lpjpokeiblobbcpfheneagcfjlcjbkhf)

There is a big bunch of useful [Trello Chrome Extensions in the Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-apps/trello).

Comment: The extension prints empty pages now (Nov 2014).